# Is it easier for the user to have all the options at a glance?

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, workflow, question-answer

I am working on an internal webapp where we ask users about very different issues.
Users have the option of not answering, but now we want to know if they really don't answer because they don't understand the question, so we want to give the option of "I don't understand the answer".

What do you think would be more user friendly? Having all the options displayed on a first screen with different buttons? Or give a button that says "skip question" and then ask the user with a pop-up?

Comment: If the user clicks "skip question", will the pop-up have more than one option? Or will it just be "I don't understand" as the sole choice?

Comment: I think there's a second option: maybe they don't answer because the UI is not friendly at all or is a graphically boring questionary. I use to do that with boring questionaries.

Comment: @musefan The pop-up will have the two options: 1) I don't want to answer the question 2) I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Danielillo The page is very simple and clear... I don't think it's a problem of UI..

Comment: you are basically saying that you want to ask questions about the questionnaire, it's basically a met-questionnaire :)

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to have least actions for Users. Generally, more clicks means less user friendly. So, No pop ups please.

In your case, it is better to have (HELP) option or intuitivetext on tooltip of (i) icon placed beside question displaying some description of question or some sample answers which guides user to enter particular data you want from them.

And, it is nothing bad to have one option saying "I don't understand the question" to still allow user skip.